# How to download and save a picture with eXist-db?

Tags: xquery, exist-db

I am using eXist-db and I am trying to download a picture and save it on local disk with XQuery. I have trIed the following code:

```
declare namespace xmldb="http://exist-db.org/xquery/xmldb";

import module namespace http="http://exist-db.org/xquery/httpclient";
import module namespace util="http://exist-db.org/xquery/util";

let $url :=
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png"
let $response := http:get(xs:anyURI($url), true(), <Headers/>)
let $picture := util:base64-decode($response//httpclient:body)
return 
    xmldb:store("/db/apps/places", "picture.png", $picture)
```

The above code downloads the picture, but when I try to open the image, I get an error.

I hope to have explained my problem well.

Comment: What version of eXist? Please be more specific about the error you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my fully commented, working sample code for downloading a file over HTTP and storing it in eXist-db at https://gist.github.com/joewiz/5938909.